# Why does my index.js file keep giving me and error even though everything is perfect?

Tags: html, reactjs, formatting, jsx, prettier

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function MyApp() {
    return { < ul > < li > < /li> <li> </li > < li > < /li></ul >
    }
}


ReactDOM.render( < MyApp / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />


    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

I have installed prettier and my code wont be "pretty". I get this error JSX

> element 'li' has no corresponding closing tag.

I have literally tried everything

Answer (score 1):

remove the spaces that are between the open/close brackets and your element

it should be like this

```
<ul> <li> </li> <li> </li> <li> </li></ul>
```

Comment: Its the exact same? Visual studio is making the space itself ....

Comment: I just tried this in repl.it server and removing the spaces fixed the problem. I'm not sure why visual studio does that but watch out for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this, whitout spaces into tags, and the return with `()` insted of `{}`.

```js
function MyApp() {
    return ( 
        <ul> 
            <li> </li>
            <li> </li>
            <li> </li>
        </ul>
    )
}
```